# Adapt GAS script functions from a Spreadsheet to a Web Application

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to `GAS` and `JavaScript` in general, so I'd like some help adapting a script from a spreadsheet to a `Web App`.

Based on some scripts I found, I developed a code to work the way I need in a `Google Spreadsheet`, but after making it work exactly the way I need it, I realized that a `Web App` could be a better alternative, mainly because of how it works on Mobile .

The point is that I didn't have a very linear `JavaScript` learning curve, my learning was solving specific needs, so I have difficulty with some basic concepts... and to be quite honest, deeply understanding `JavaScript` is not my main focus, but this knowledge is missing me now...

**Let's get straight to the point**

My current spreadsheet is this one:
[Google Sheet - Stack Demonstration](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit?usp=sharing)

In the `GAS` linked to this worksheet there are 2 `.gs` files and one `HTML`.

**GAS files**

**1 - CSV.gs | Contains 2 scripts**

`CheckForFiles` - Checks the amount of files in a given `Google Drive` folder before releasing the execution of other scripts.

`SheetToCSV` - Creates a `.csv` file of the sheet in the parent folder of that sheet.
This script is applied to the spreadsheet's **`Submit`** button.

**2 - Upload.gs | Contains some functions responsible for uploading files through the spreadsheet.**

`ShowDialog0101` - Basically it's a script to call the upload page through an `HTML` alert in the spreadsheet.

`GetParent` - Basically it's a script that discovers the ID of the spreadsheet's parent folder and passes this information to the HTML file. I created this function because that way I can use this worksheet's folder as a model folder, simply duplicating the entire content without having to edit the code to update the worksheet's folder ID.

`CreateOrGetFolder` - This is the main function of the upload script, it checks if there is a child folder that has the name "Video" inside the parent folder, if it exists, it takes the ID of that folder so that the file is uploaded in that folder, if it does not exist, it creates a folder called "Video" and takes the ID of the created folder.

This is the `Web App` that launches when the **Video File** button is clicked:

[Web App - Stack Demonstration](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZ81u7x47Ettd589x730yLILkiVX0TJoVh289hR8PxayTbzYqcKUsilIXefSpk5o2E4w/exec)

**HTML file**

Basically contains the client-side upload functions, I adapted this script based on [this one.](https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload)

**What i would like to do**

As I commented initially, I would like to adapt these scripts to work in a `Web App`.

My idea is that instead of the person filling out the worksheet, they fill out a form.

For this I need to adapt mainly the `SheetToCSV` script to link with a **`Submit`** button in the `Web App`, the idea is that as soon as the form is completed and the file upload is completed, this button is released and then when clicking on it the `SheetToCSV` script be triggered by creating a `.csv` file in the spreadsheet's parent folder with all the form responses.

My main difficulty is in linking the `.csv` generation script with the **`Submit`** button, I've been racking my brains over this for days.

I'm already having nightmares with this programming, literally... if anyone can help me with this, I'd be very grateful!

**EDIT**

**I'll try to explain in a little more detail here.**

Currently, I have this google spreadsheet here:
[image: Spreadsheet]

This worksheet contains modified versions of **2 scripts** created by Tanaike.

**Script 1** - Generates a `.csv` file with the worksheet fields in the same folder as the worksheet.

**Script 2** - It is a modified version of Tanaike's [Resumable Upload for Web Apps](https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps) script, it is called in the spreadsheet via `html alert`.

[image: Spreadsheet explanation]

**Resumable Upload for Web Apps via HTML Alert**
[image: HTML Alert]

**CSV file generated by the worksheet**

[image: CSV File]

Everything works as expected in this worksheet, but now I would like to convert it to a `Web App`, like this example:

[image: HTML Form]

The issue is that I don't know how to convert Tanaike's `.csv` generation script to generate the files through this html form, what I need is to integrate it with the **`Submit`** button of the `Web App` and collect the form fields in a `.csv` file.

The **Spreadsheet** and the **Web App** can be viewed at these links:

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit#gid=0)

[Web App Form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbznqY2J4zrikj06fn9COV5mWfTjZebWK1ynhpZGkMLOi06j8vKfPi21BlJBPR7djh_-kQ/exec)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My idea is that instead of the person filling out the worksheet, they fill out a form. For this I need to adapt mainly the SheetToCSV script to link with a Submit button in the Web App, the idea is that as soon as the form is completed and the file upload is completed, this button is released and then when clicking on it the SheetToCSV script be triggered by creating a .csv file in the spreadsheet's parent folder with all the form responses.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Of course! I'll try to explain better. Currently the `.csv` file is generated when the person clicks the `Submit` button on this worksheet, my goal now is for the `.csv` file to be generated through a form published in the `Web App`, the idea is to add the same fields that exist in that worksheet in the `Web App` , and when the person clicks the Web App's Submit button, the `.csv` file is generated in the spreadsheet folder. This way, the spreadsheet will only serve as a reference for the `Web App` to know where to create the `.csv` file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to make the user upload a CSV file using HTML form and that you want to put the uploaded CSV file in a specific folder. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Close to that, I want the `HTML form` information to be populated in the `.csv` file that will be created when I click on the `Submit` button. This form will also have a button to upload a video file, the video file upload script is already in the `GAS` of the demo worksheet. [You can view the upload script here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZ81u7x47Ettd589x730yLILkiVX0TJoVh289hR8PxayTbzYqcKUsilIXefSpk5o2E4w/exec)

Comment: Basically, the idea is to add fields to the HTML [of this Upload Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZ81u7x47Ettd589x730yLILkiVX0TJoVh289hR8PxayTbzYqcKUsilIXefSpk5o2E4w/exec) and generate a `.csv` with the form responses when clicking `Submit`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I cannot still understand your goal. And, when I saw your Web Apps, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of your Web Apps? And also, I cannot imagine `Basically, the idea is to add fields to the HTML of this Upload Web App and generate a .csv with the form responses when clicking Submit`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Of course, no problem! I will try to explain more directly. I have [this Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxZ81u7x47Ettd589x730yLILkiVX0TJoVh289hR8PxayTbzYqcKUsilIXefSpk5o2E4w/exec), I would like to add fields to it to make it an HTML form, I would like the answers filled in it to be saved in a new `.csv` file every time it is `submitted`. You can view all the code for this `Web App` [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1odCFR8_jEnxVDYfQNQx0uVf37uSN5iAJ7ucwwK2OgcY/edit?usp=sharing). If you still can't understand, I'm willing to clarify any point, please let me know.

Comment: No problem, my English isn't very good either... I edited the question and tried to explain in more detail., see if you can understand, any questions please ask me. Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. About `The issue is that I don't know how to convert Tanaike's .csv generation script to generate the files through this html form, what I need is to integrate it with the Submit button of the Web App and collect the form fields in a .csv file.`, in this case, you are not required to put the value to Spreadsheet as shown in the question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No problem, thank you for your attention. Exactly, there is no need for the value to be placed in the spreadsheet, only in the `.csv`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, you want to retrieve the values from your new HTML form, and want to create a CSV file using the retrieved values. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, where do you want to create the CSV file in?

Comment: Exactly! I would like the .csv to be created in the worksheet folder, if possible, the values ​​do not need to be there, it would only serve as a reference. If this is too much work, the .csv can be created in any folder on the Google Drive.

Comment: By the way, when I saw your updated script, the same names are used for `<input id="name01" type="text"` and `<input id="description" type="text"`. And also, `<select class="custom-select" id="gender2">` is used 2 times for `<h6>Option 01</h6>` and `<h6>Option 02</h6>`. In this case, I would like to recommend confirming your whole script again. By this, I'm worried that even when these are modified, your actual situation might be different. I apologize for this.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I ended up forgetting to change the ID of some elements, but the real situation will be the same, feel free to change anything in this script that is published

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your expected values for the CSV data? In this case, you want to retrieve 2 text values of `name01`, `description`, and 2 values from dropdown lists of `Option1` and `Option2`. The total values are 4 values. Is my understanding correct? And, in your situation, when the HTML form is submitted, you want to create a new CSV file for every submission. Is my understanding correct? I deeply apologize that I try to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Your understanding is totally correct, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for your patience and effort to understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my understanding was correct. So, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your expected values for the CSV data? In this case,

I confirmed your expected result in this question as follows.

- You want to retrieve 2 text values of "name01", "description", and 2 values from dropdown lists of "Option1" and "Option2". The total values are 4 values.
- When the HTML form is submitted, you want to create a new CSV file for every submission.

In this case, how about the following modification? Unfortunately, in your question, your script is not shown. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a simple modification.

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet including your script, when the submit button is clicked, it seems that the function `submitForm()` is run. In this answer, this is used.

#### Modified script:

##### Javascript side:

Please modify `submitForm()` as follows.

```js
function submitForm() {

  // Added the below script.
  var name = $('#name01').val();
  var description = $('#description').val();
  var option1 = $('#Option1').val();
  var option2 = $('#Option2').val();
  var data = [name, description, option1, option2].join(",");
  google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);

  if ($('#submit-btn.disabled')[0]) return; // short circuit
```

##### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following function. Please modify the filename of `"sample.csv"` to your actual situation.

```js
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile("sample.csv", data);
```

- By this modification, 4 values in HTML form are retrieved and save it as a CSV file to the folder of `uploadParentFolderId`.
- If you want to save the file to other folder, please modify `uploadParentFolderId` of `google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId)`.

Comment: This is perfect!!!
Really, really thank you for helping me with this, I've been breaking my head for days and trying things that never work as expected. It will bring my sleep again... Thank you very much!

Comment: If you allow me to ask, I would also like to know what is the best way to integrate the **CheckForFiles( )** function in this HTML form, I created this function in my spreadsheet to check the amount of existing CSV files in a subfolder of the worksheet folder. The goal is to pause the script after 3 submissions.

Comment: If you take a look at the existing **sheetToCsv0101( )** function in this worksheet, you will see that I made some changes so that it creates some more CSV's according to some conditions, the values ​​contained in these CSV's are irrelevant, they only serve as a record for the script to stop running afterwards of 3 submissions.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's better for me to open another question and detail the question better. I'll try to develop, if I can't I'll create another question. Again, thank you so much for all your help and patience!

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new questions, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new questions. But, I would like to support you. And, from `I think it's better for me to open another question and detail the question better.`, when I saw your new questions, I will check them and try to understand them. When I could correctly understand them, I would like to answer them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the support! I'm testing some things, if I really can't solve it, I'll open a new question tomorrow. Until later!

Comment: You helped me the other day with this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187545/detect-in-which-folder-a-file-should-be-uploaded/75190640?noredirect=1#), in it you explained how to get the next empty folder to upload a file through my HTML form.

Comment: Now I would like to know if it is possible to use the same name of that folder to generate the file .csv that you taught me here in this question. That is, I would like the generated file to have a name like "01-01" "01-02", instead of being called "Sample.csv". It is possible?

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Of course, I completely understand. I asked a new question about this just now, if you can take the time to look at it later I would be very grateful. Thanks so much for all your help and support.