# Detect in which folder a file should be uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like some help to adjust an upload script, my goal is for the script to detect in which folder a file should be uploaded.

I created an `HTML` [form](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby-nDNhsCRCNRQfnpKZXmjEG77_uhv3sO_Qf0Lz-ASA9vfnMI376Hqd22SHbgErn0REwQ/exec) in a `Google Web App`, this is my `HTML` form:

[image]

This form has 2 files, the `.gs` file has this code here:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms0101.html').evaluate();
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}


function getParent(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var parent = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents().next().getId();
  return parent
}

function getLimitFolder(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pastapai = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getId();
  return limitfolder
}

const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile("sample.csv", data);

/**
* creates a folder under a parent folder, and returns it's id. If the folder already exists
* then it is not created and it simply returns the id of the existing one
*/
function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId),
      folder;

    if (parentFolder) {
      var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
      if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
        video_folder = foldersIter.next().getFoldersByName(folderName); //folderName esta definido no arquivo forms.html
        if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
        folder = video_folder.next();
        }
      } else {
        folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
        folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }

    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

// NOTE: always make sure we use DriveApp, even if it's in a comment, for google to import those
// libraries and allow the rest of the app to work. see https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
```

The `HTML` file has exactly this code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drive Multi Large File Upload</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
     
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
      
      .disclaimer{
        width: 480px; 
        color: #646464;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding:0 16px;
        text-align:center;
        font:400 12px Rubik,sans-serif;
        }

      h5.center-align.teal-text {
        font:700 26px Rubik,sans-serif;
        color: #00F498!important;
      }

      .row {
        font:600 14px Rubik,sans-serif;
      }

      .btn {
        background-color: black;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        background-color: #00F498;
      }

      body {
        margin-top: -40px;
      }

      #progress {
        color: #00000;
      }
      
      .disclaimer a{
        color: #00BCAA;
        }

      #credit{
        display:none
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
 <div id="forminner">
  <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">YOUR NAME</h5>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="name01" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">SOME DESCRIPTION</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="description" type="text" name="Description" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name">Description</label>
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <h6>Model</h6>       
        <select class="custom-select" id="Model">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
        </select> 
          &nbsp;

        <h6>Color</h6>        
        <select class="custom-select" id="Color">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
        </select>   
      </div>
  </div>

    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Upload the Video File</h5>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
            <div id="input-btn" class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input id="files" type="file" single="">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Select the file">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <button id="submit-btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 hide" id="update">
            <hr>
            <p>
              Por favor, aguarde enquanto seu arquivo está sendo carregado.<br><span style="color: #00000;"><b>Não feche ou atualize a janela durante o upload.</b></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id="progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Tudo certo!</h5>
        <p>Se você já preencheu todos os campos é só fechar essa janela e clicar em enviar!</p>
        <button id="fechar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" style ="transform: translateX(160%);" type="button" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

    <script>

      var upload_folder = "01-01"
      const chunkSize = 5242880;
      const uploadParentFolderId = <?=getParent()?>; // creates a folder inside of this folder
      const limitfolder = <?=getLimitFolder()?>;

      function closer(){
        google.script.host.close();
      }

      function submitForm() {

        // Added the below script.
        if ($('#submit-btn.disabled')[0]) return; // short circuit

        var name = upload_folder
        var files = [...$('#files')[0].files]; // convert from FileList to array

        
        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Por favor, selecione um arquivo");
          return;
        }

        var name = $('#name01').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var model = $('#Model').val();
        var color = $('#Color').val();
        var form_values = [name, description, model, color];
        form_values = form_values.map(r => r.replaceAll(",", "#")); // Essa linha substitui todas as "," por "#" antes de gerar o .csv
        var data = form_values.join(",");
        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, limitfolder);

        disableForm(); // prevent re submission

        // the map and reduce are here to ensure that only one file is uploaded at a time. This allows
        // the promises to be run sequentially
        files.map(file => uploadFilePromiseFactory(file))
            .reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
              return promiseChain.then(currentTask);
            }, Promise.resolve([])).then( () => {
              console.log("Completed all files upload");
              showSuccess();
            });
      }

      function disableForm() {
        $('#submit-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#input-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#update').removeClass('hide');
         $('#update').removeClass('hide');
      }

      function uploadFilePromiseFactory(file) {
        return () => {
          console.log("Processing: ", file.name);
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            showProgressMessage("Seu arquivo está sendo carregado");

            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            // not sure of a better way of passing the promise functions down
            fr.resolve = () => resolve();
            fr.reject = (error) => reject(error);
            fr.onload = onFileReaderLoad;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          });
        };
      }
      
      /**
       * Gets called once the browser has loaded a file. The main logic that creates a folder
       * and initiates the file upload resides here
       */
      function onFileReaderLoad(onLoadEvent) {
        var fr = this;

        var newFolderName = upload_folder
        createOrGetFolder(newFolderName, uploadParentFolderId).then(newFolderId => {
          console.log("Found or created guest folder with id: ", newFolderId);
          uploadFileToDriveFolder.call(fr, newFolderId).then(() => {
              fr.resolve();
            }, (error) => {
              fr.reject(error);
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error) {
              showError(error.toString());
            }
            console.log("onFileReaderLoad Error2: ", error);
          });

      }

      /**
       * call to the DriveApp api. Wrapped in a promise in case I want to address timing issues between a
       * createFolder and findFolderById
       */
      function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
            console.log("createOrGetFolder response: ", response);
            if (response && response.length) {
              resolve(response);
            }
            reject(response);
          }).createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function uploadFileToDriveFolder(parentFolderId) {
        var fr = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var fileName = fr.fileName;
          var fileSize = fr.fileSize;
          var fileType = fr.fileType;
          console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
          var buf = fr.result;
          var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
          var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
          var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
               data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
               length: e.numByte,
               range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
          });
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(oAuthToken => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + oAuthToken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
              mimeType: fileType,
              name: fileName,
              parents: [parentFolderId]
            }));
            xhr.onload = () => {
              doUpload(fileName, {
                location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                chunks: chunks,
              }).then(success => {
                resolve(success);
                console.log("Successfully uploaded: ", fileName);
              },
              error => {
                reject(error);
              });
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log("ERROR: ", xhr.response);
              reject(xhr.response);
            };
          }).getOAuthToken();
        });
      }

      function showSuccess() {
        $('#forminner').hide();
        $('#success').show();
        $('#fechar').show();
      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#update').html(e);
      }

      function showProgressMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function doUpload(fileName, e) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" + "0%</span>");
          var chunks = e.chunks;
          var location = e.location;
          var cnt = 0;
          var end = chunks.length;
          var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            console.log("content range: ", e.range);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" 
                       + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>" );
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    $("#progress").text("Done.");
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                    reject();
                }
            };
          }(cnt);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, currently the upload folder is hardcoded in the script and is defined in the variable `var upload_folder = "01-01"`.

Taking a look at my form, notice that I have a field called **Model**, this field is important to define the model of the client's request.

[image]

The issue is that each folder should only contain a single file, so I created several upload folders following this pattern:

```
01-01, 01-02, 01-03, 02-01, 02-02, 02-03...
```

The first number refers to the model selected on the form, the second number refers to the **slot used**.

[image]

What I need is that, according to the model selected in the form, the script checks which folder referring to that model does not yet have a file and uploads the video file to that folder.

### Exemplifying

**Model 01 was selected in the form**

The script checks if folder 01-01 has a file, if it does, it uploads the file to folder 01-02, if that is also busy, it uploads the file to folder 01-03.

**Model 02 was selected in the form**

The script checks if folder 02-01 has a file, if it does, it uploads the file to folder 02-02, if that is also busy, it uploads the file to folder 02-03.

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, so I have some difficulty with this type of operation involving Client and Server... besides, I couldn't think of any way to get to this result without filling the code with IF/Else.

I would be very grateful with any help.

### EDIT

After Tanaike's suggestion, the script is close to working as expected, the issue is that for some reason the first folder is generated with an extra `-01` looking like this:

[image]

Another point is that when I change the option in the form, for example `02`, the folder taken into account continues to be `01`, that is, even if `02` is selected in the form, the script uploads the file to the next empty folder `01`.

[image]

I tried to modify the variable `var upload_folder = "01-01";` to `var upload_folder = $('#Model').val();` but this way the folder created is `Choose...-01`, I believe this happens because it would be necessary to return the information from `$('#Model').val()` to the `.gs` file somehow.

I would also like that when the third folder of the selected model is exceeded, the script displays an error popup instead of continuing to create more folders, that is, if the option `01` is selected in the form's model field and folders `01-01, 01-02, 01-03` are full, it is not to create a `01-04` but to display a message like `Wait for model 01 release`.

**I've made the upload folder access free so you can see exactly what's going on:**

[Stack Thread - Demonstration Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1gv_hJH9qDG_FyH2v6bgreYNBavL64u2T)

Comment: is .gs files a typo? should it be .js files?  Also, what are you using on the server side?  Are you able to use mysql or some other database on the server?

Comment: It's not a typo, it's a `.gs`, this HTML form was created inside the GAS, for that reason I believe that I can only use `JS`, `CSS` and `HTML`.

Comment: what are you using on the server side?

Comment: I'm only using JavaScript, HTML and CSS, the server side code is all in the HTML document. To make it easier to understand, [here's the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iwlljDPgN6xnmgP5EyOMwguRJ9axY3ZWQlL_Sag55U/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet where GAS is linked, I don't know if you're familiar with GAS, if you're not, just click on Apps Script in the Extensions menu.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following expected result,

- each folder should only contain a single file
- The script checks if folder 01-01 has a file, if it does, it uploads the file to folder 01-02, if that is also busy, it uploads the file to folder 01-03.
- The script checks if folder 02-01 has a file, if it does, it uploads the file to folder 02-02, if that is also busy, it uploads the file to folder 02-03.

How about modifying your script as follows?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your function `createOrGetFolder` is modified.

```js
function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId), folder;
    if (parentFolder) {
      var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
      if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
        var videoFolder = foldersIter.next();
        var nextFolderName = folderName + "-01";
        while (!folder) {
          video_folder = videoFolder.getFoldersByName(nextFolderName);
          if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
            folder = video_folder.next();
            var files = folder.getFiles();
            if (files.hasNext()) {
              var [a, b] = nextFolderName.split("-");
              nextFolderName = `${a}-${String(Number(b) + 1).padStart(2, "0")}`;
              folder = null;
            }
          } else {
            folder = videoFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
          }
        }
      } else {
        folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
        folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }
    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

- When I saw your HTML, for example, when `02` is selected from "Model", the value of it is `02`. So, in this modification, in order to scan the folders and files in each folder, I used `02-01` as the 1st search folder.
- By this modification, for example, when `folderName` is `02`, the folder names of `02-01`, `02-02`,,, are searched. When the files are not found in the folder, the folder ID is returned.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### Added:

About `01-01-01` folder, in this case, it is considered that in your javascript, you are retrieving the value from the dropdown list with `var model = $('#Model').val();` (in this case, the values are 01, 02, 03,,,), but, as the default folder name, you are using `var upload_folder = "01-01"`. I think that this is the reason for your new 1st issue. So, please modify `var upload_folder = "01-01"` to `var upload_folder = "01"`.

And, in your javascript, by `var newFolderName = upload_folder`, the same folder name of `upload_folder` is always used. I think that this is the reason for your new 2nd issue. So, please modify them as follows.

#### From:

```
var upload_folder = "01-01"
```

#### To:

```
var upload_folder = "01";
```

And,

#### From:

```
var name = $('#name01').val();
var description = $('#description').val();
var model = $('#Model').val();
var color = $('#Color').val();
```

#### To:

```
var name = $('#name01').val();
var description = $('#description').val();
var model = $('#Model').val();
upload_folder = model;
var color = $('#Color').val();
```

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you very much for your help and attention, your contributions have helped me a lot. As for the modification suggestion, I've done some testing and it's very close to working as expected, I've edited my question to show what's happening now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in editing, I was testing a few more things, but I tried to explain in detail what is happening now. If you have any questions or difficulties understanding something, please let me know.

Comment: By the way, this script presented in the note to not change the Web App ID is genius! It will be very useful in everyday life.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I modified only your Google Apps Script. I apologize for this. From your new 2 issues, I noticed that your Javascript is also required to be modified. I apologize for this. For your new 2 issues, I added 2 more modification points. Please confirm it.

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it! Again, thank you very much for your help and patience in explaining.

Comment: Hey, if it's not too much to ask, could you tell me how to retrieve the value of `folder` to use as the `csv` file creation name instead of "Sample.csv"?

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Hey, if it's not too much to ask, could you tell me how to retrieve the value of folder to use as the csv file creation name instead of "Sample.csv"?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: Sure, no problem! I had made a question asking about this today, maybe it got a little confusing, but [here is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75195513/get-the-value-of-the-variable-outside-the-function-to-create-a-file/75196156#75196156), if you can't understand it, please let me know. Basically I would like to get the value of the `folder` variable outside the function so that this value can be applied to the name of a file that will be created.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. From your reply, I confirmed that you had posted your new question as new question. And also, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I believe that your new question will be resolved by the answerer.

Comment: That's fine no problem! I'm trying to follow the approach suggested in the answer, using PropertyService, but I don't know if that's right. But I will keep trying. Thank you so much for all your support and patience!

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. About `using PropertyService, but I don't know if that's right.`, I agree with your comment. But, now, I noticed that you have provided your whole script in your new question. I believe that by this, your issue will be resolved more clearly.