# Get the value of the variable outside the function to create a file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I would like to know how I can return the name of the folder created in the `folder` variable outside the `createOrGetFolder` function, the intention is to be able to create a file with the same name as the folder created, in this code here:

```
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(folder, data);
```

This is my complete code from the `.gs` file:

```
/**
* Modified script written by Tanaike and CharlesPlucker
*
* Additional Script by Tyrone
* version 20.01.2023.1
*/

        function doGet(e) {
          return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms0101.html').evaluate();
        }
        
        
        function getOAuthToken() {
          return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
        }
        
        
        function getParent(){
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var id = ss.getId();
          var parent = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents().next().getId();
          return parent
        }
        
        function getLimitFolder(){
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var pastapai = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
          var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getId();
          return limitfolder
        }
        
        /**
        * creates a folder under a parent folder, and returns it's id. If the folder already exists
        * then it is not created and it simply returns the id of the existing one
        */
        
        function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
          try {
            var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId), folder;
            if (parentFolder) {
              var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
              if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
                var videoFolder = foldersIter.next();
                var nextFolderName = folderName + "-01";
                while (!folder) {
                  video_folder = videoFolder.getFoldersByName(nextFolderName);
                  if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
                    folder = video_folder.next();
                    var files = folder.getFiles();
                    if (files.hasNext()) {
                      var [a, b] = nextFolderName.split("-");
                      nextFolderName = `${a}-${String(Number(b) + 1).padStart(2, "0")}`;
                      folder = null;
                    }
                  } else {
                    folder = videoFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
                  }
                }
              } else {
                folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
                folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
              }
            } else {
              throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
            }
            return folder.getId();
          } catch (error) {
            return error;
          }
        }
        
        const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile("Sample.csv", data);
    
    
    // NOTE: always make sure we use DriveApp, even if it's in a comment, for google to import those
    // libraries and allow the rest of the app to work. see https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
```

Note that in `const saveDataAsCSV` the currently file creation name is `Sample.csv`, and this is where I want to apply the `folder` variable that is in the function `createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId)`

And this is the complete code of the `HTML` file:

```
/**
* Modified script written by Tanaike and CharlesPlucker
*
* Additional Script by Tyrone
* version 20.01.2023.1
*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drive Multi Large File Upload</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
     
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
      
      .disclaimer{
        width: 480px; 
        color: #646464;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding:0 16px;
        text-align:center;
        font:400 12px Rubik,sans-serif;
        }

      h5.center-align.teal-text {
        font:700 26px Rubik,sans-serif;
        color: #00F498!important;
      }

      .row {
        font:600 14px Rubik,sans-serif;
      }

      .btn {
        background-color: black;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        background-color: #00F498;
      }

      body {
        margin-top: -40px;
      }

      #progress {
        color: #00000;
      }
      
      .disclaimer a{
        color: #00BCAA;
        }

      #credit{
        display:none
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
 <div id="forminner">
  <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">YOUR NAME</h5>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="name01" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">SOME DESCRIPTION</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="description" type="text" name="Description" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name">Description</label>
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <h6>Model</h6>       
        <select class="custom-select" id="Model">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
        </select> 
          &nbsp;

        <h6>Color</h6>        
        <select class="custom-select" id="Color">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
        </select>   
      </div>
  </div>

    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Upload the Video File</h5>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
            <div id="input-btn" class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input id="files" type="file" single="">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Select the file">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <button id="submit-btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 hide" id="update">
            <hr>
            <p>
              Por favor, aguarde enquanto seu arquivo está sendo carregado.<br><span style="color: #00000;"><b>Não feche ou atualize a janela durante o upload.</b></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id="progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Tudo certo!</h5>
        <p>Se você já preencheu todos os campos é só fechar essa janela e clicar em enviar!</p>
        <button id="fechar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" style ="transform: translateX(160%);" type="button" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

    <script>

      var upload_folder = "01";
      const chunkSize = 5242880;
      const uploadParentFolderId = <?=getParent()?>; // creates a folder inside of this folder
      const limitfolder = <?=getLimitFolder()?>;

      function closer(){
        google.script.host.close();
      }

      function submitForm() {

        // Added the below script.
        if ($('#submit-btn.disabled')[0]) return; // short circuit

        var name = upload_folder
        var files = [...$('#files')[0].files]; // convert from FileList to array

        
        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Por favor, selecione um arquivo");
          return;
        }

        var name = $('#name01').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var model = $('#Model').val();
        upload_folder = model;
        var color = $('#Color').val();
        var form_values = [name, description, model, color];
        form_values = form_values.map(r => r.replaceAll(",", "#")); // Essa linha substitui todas as "," por "#" antes de gerar o .csv
        var data = form_values.join(",");
        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, limitfolder);

        disableForm(); // prevent re submission

        // the map and reduce are here to ensure that only one file is uploaded at a time. This allows
        // the promises to be run sequentially
        files.map(file => uploadFilePromiseFactory(file))
            .reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
              return promiseChain.then(currentTask);
            }, Promise.resolve([])).then( () => {
              console.log("Completed all files upload");
              showSuccess();
            });
      }

      function disableForm() {
        $('#submit-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#input-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#update').removeClass('hide');
         $('#update').removeClass('hide');
      }

      function uploadFilePromiseFactory(file) {
        return () => {
          console.log("Processing: ", file.name);
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            showProgressMessage("Seu arquivo está sendo carregado");

            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            // not sure of a better way of passing the promise functions down
            fr.resolve = () => resolve();
            fr.reject = (error) => reject(error);
            fr.onload = onFileReaderLoad;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          });
        };
      }
      
      /**
       * Gets called once the browser has loaded a file. The main logic that creates a folder
       * and initiates the file upload resides here
       */
      function onFileReaderLoad(onLoadEvent) {
        var fr = this;

        var newFolderName = upload_folder
        createOrGetFolder(newFolderName, uploadParentFolderId).then(newFolderId => {
          console.log("Found or created guest folder with id: ", newFolderId);
          uploadFileToDriveFolder.call(fr, newFolderId).then(() => {
              fr.resolve();
            }, (error) => {
              fr.reject(error);
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error) {
              showError(error.toString());
            }
            console.log("onFileReaderLoad Error2: ", error);
          });

      }

      /**
       * call to the DriveApp api. Wrapped in a promise in case I want to address timing issues between a
       * createFolder and findFolderById
       */
      function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
            console.log("createOrGetFolder response: ", response);
            if (response && response.length) {
              resolve(response);
            }
            reject(response);
          }).createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function uploadFileToDriveFolder(parentFolderId) {
        var fr = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var fileName = fr.fileName;
          var fileSize = fr.fileSize;
          var fileType = fr.fileType;
          console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
          var buf = fr.result;
          var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
          var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
          var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
               data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
               length: e.numByte,
               range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
          });
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(oAuthToken => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + oAuthToken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
              mimeType: fileType,
              name: fileName,
              parents: [parentFolderId]
            }));
            xhr.onload = () => {
              doUpload(fileName, {
                location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                chunks: chunks,
              }).then(success => {
                resolve(success);
                console.log("Successfully uploaded: ", fileName);
              },
              error => {
                reject(error);
              });
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log("ERROR: ", xhr.response);
              reject(xhr.response);
            };
          }).getOAuthToken();
        });
      }

      function showSuccess() {
        $('#forminner').hide();
        $('#success').show();
        $('#fechar').show();
      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#update').html(e);
      }

      function showProgressMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function doUpload(fileName, e) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" + "0%</span>");
          var chunks = e.chunks;
          var location = e.location;
          var cnt = 0;
          var end = chunks.length;
          var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            console.log("content range: ", e.range);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" 
                       + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>" );
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    $("#progress").text("Done.");
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                    reject();
                }
            };
          }(cnt);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

As `folder` is without the `var` prefix, I figured it should work, as in theory this makes it a global variable... however I still get the `folder is undefined` message in the console.

I also tried calling the function before the file creation code, like this:

```
createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(folder, data);
```

But that way I get the message `folderName is undefined.`

---

Based on the suggestion made in the [The WizEd answer's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75196156/1595451), this was my last attempt:

Modified excerpt in the `.gs` file:

```
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(newFolderId, data);
```

Modified excerpt in the `HTML` file:

```
       var newFolderId = "";
      /**
       * call to the DriveApp api. Wrapped in a promise in case I want to address timing issues between a
       * createFolder and findFolderById
       */
      function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
            console.log("createOrGetFolder response: ", response);
            if (response && response.length) {
              resolve(response);
            }
            reject(response);
          }).createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
          newFolderId = createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
        });
      }
```

That way I still can't get the name of the folder created or used...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is `DriveApp`? Check its documentation to see if there's a way to get the name from the `folder` object.

Comment: You can return the `folder` object instead of `folder.getId()`. Then the caller should be able to get the filename from this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `GAS` Tag, this is a script created within `Google App Script`. As for the suggested change, is it possible to return both somehow (`return folder.getId()` and `return folder`)? I need the folder `ID` for another code step.

Comment: You can return them in an array `return [folder.getId(), folder]`, but why? If you return `folder`, the caller can use `getId()` to get the ID from it.

Comment: Right! Quite frankly, I don't know, I asked because I figured it might be a short cut, I have very little experience with JavaScript. What happens is that the `createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId)` function is called by the client side, as soon as an HTML form is submitted, so I believe that the way to receive the value of this variable is a little more complicated than the common... you can understand a little better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187545/detect-in-which-folder-a-file-should-be-uploaded).

Comment: "I did some research, and tried a few things, but I couldn't get it to work. I will be grateful for any help." it's just chitchat. Instead add links to the most relevant questions found on this site explain what was not clear, show what yout tried . Regarding the code included, its not clear how you are tried to use it. Please describe how the function will be called, add some sample input parameters and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Global variable are not persistent.  What that means is when a function is executed the instance creates the global variable but releases it when the function or function chain finishes.

Here `func1()` calls `func2()` so the instance of the global variable is perserved.

However if I run `func2()` by itself following running `func1()` it is reset to blank

**Run func1()**

```
var globalVariable = "";

function func1 () {
  try {
    console.log("globalVariable in func1 = ["+globalVariable+"]")
    globalVariable = "Hello";
    func2();
    console.log("globalVariable from func2 = ["+globalVariable+"]")
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in func1: "+err);
  }
}

function func2 () {
  try {
    console.log("globalVariable in func2 = ["+globalVariable+"]")
    globalVariable = "Good bye";
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in func2: "+err);
  }
}

11:53:15 AM Notice  Execution started
11:53:17 AM Info    globalVariable in func1 = []
11:53:17 AM Info    globalVariable in func2 = [Hello]
11:53:17 AM Info    globalVariable from func2 = [Good bye]
11:53:16 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Now run func2()**

```
11:57:38 AM Notice  Execution started
11:57:39 AM Info    globalVariable in func2 = []
11:57:39 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

To perserve the value of globalVariable from one execution to the next you need to use [PropertyService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research and try your suggestion. I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I don't really want to delve into it, my area of ​​expertise is different, but every now and then I need to solve some things...

Comment: Of course it does.  It shows how in one function you can create a variable with global scope for use in another function.

Comment: Global variables *are* persistent. Local variables go away when the function ends. If the variable is going away, you must be restarting the JavaScript process.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately the answer isn't complete/clear. In Google Apps Script the JavaScript process is restarted when calling a function from the Google editor UI like Google Sheets, a Google Apps Script trigger, etc. Some times this is explanined  as "the whole project is loaded on every execution".

Comment: @TheWizEd I've updated my question and added my complete code, can you explain me better how I can use `PropertyService` in this situation? I still haven't been able to solve it, I'm trying to understand if this is really the way to achieve what I need, I have a lot of difficulty understanding these flows between client and server.

Comment: In the client create a global variable `var newFolderId = "";`.  Then when you call `createOrGetFolder` set the variable `newFolderId = createOrGetFolder(...);`, the return value from that function call.  Now you have the `newFolderId` available for any subsequent function calls.

Comment: Be careful of the `.then(...)` in `createOrGetFolder(newFolderName, uploadParentFolderId).then(newFolderId => {` as the `newFolderId` is a variable local to the arrow function.

Comment: @TheWizEd Excuse my lack of knowledge... I still can't get this to work... I really have very little experience with client and server operations... I edited my question with the last attempt I made based on what I understood from your answer . If possible, I would ask you to edit your answer to indicate where I need to put this information exactly. Thank you for your attention and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is so complicated I tried to figure out where you want `newFolderId` returned to use in `saveDataAsCSV`.  There are so many nested functions and Promises.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a web application using Google Apps Script. The client-side code calls the server side function `createOrGetFolder`. You want that this function returns the name of the Folder object assigned to the `folder` variable.

Currently the server side function `createOrGetFolder` on success returns the folder id (`return folder.getId();`).

To get the folder name you could use `folder.getName()` but changing the return of this function implies to make changes to the client-side code.

One option is to add a a client function to get the folder name. This could be done by calling a server side function using the folder id that currently returns `createOrGetFolder`. Another way is, to make that `createOrGetFolder` store the folder name using the Properties Service, the Cache Service, or other store to save the folder name then using a client side function retrieve this value. In both options is very likely that the changes to the html / gs files will be minimal but this will not deliver an optimal overall performance of your web application as Google Apps Script services are slow.

Another option is to change the `createOrGetFolder` function return but that implies investing time on studying the client side code and changing multiple lines of code, probably will be more expensive in programmer hours than the first option but might warrant that your web application will have an optimal overall permorance by keeping the calls to the Google Apps Script services at minimum.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The client-server flow is a little clearer, but I confess that it is still very confusing for me... I'm used to dealing with GAS directly in spreadsheets, so I never had to worry about passing information back and forth... my intention here is to learn how to do it, I have no intention of hiring a more experienced programmer because a good part of the reason for this project is to understand how to make this communication, so that in the future I will know how to ask someone for this, and I will also be able to do the my modifications more accurately.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you demonstrate one of the options you presented applied directly to my code? I know it may seem lazy on my part, but my intention is really to learn, and I've already learned a lot by observing the logic of how some codes work. I've been trying things for a few days now, I haven't published these attempts because it would make publishing a mess and even more confusing... it's been a long shot without understanding exactly how it works.

Comment: I don't think that I will do that soon, but I work / find on a related [mcve], I  might comeback and add it or a link here. In the mean time I suggest you to spend some time studying HTML Service Client-Server communication and JavaScript  Promises (a couple of related links added to the answer). Also you could spend some time learning from related questions from this site... Unfortunately the "Related" panel on the right side doesn't include question close to what you are looking.

Comment: Maybe in the [Google Apps Script chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community) you could get help to find more specific related quetions.

Comment: ok, I'll study the articles you recommended. Thank you for your attention and for your time.