# In Google Apps Script , i have a function that retrieves an array from a sheet- i want to have that array available to another function

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am new to coding within Apps Script which i understand is a subset of Java Script.

I'm making a version of the card game Regicide that runs in Google Sheets.

I have a function that reads an array (tavern) from the google sheet. I need to use this array outside of that function. But other functions don't know about it because it was created within the 1st function.

Thanks for any help offered

I can successfully read the data from the sheet, i can see that it's there - with console.log(tavern) within the 1st function.
i have tried declaring the array with var outside of the function, then within the function i just update the values within it.
But when i try and access that array in a different function - i either get [] which is how i declare it at the top (var tavern = []) or i get array is undefined.

Comment: The question is similar to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75195513/get-the-value-of-the-variable-outside-the-function-to-create-a-file/75196156?noredirect=1#comment132705535_75196156.  My answer is the same whether its a value or an array.

Comment: thanks, that thread had a lot of useful information that was pertinent to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your array and are ready to assign it (let's say the array is assigned to a variable 'myArray'), use **PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('array',myArray)**
This will save your array as a key:value property of the document that you can access at any time with **PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('array')**

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like just what i need, i'll try it out now

Comment: i haven't yet got it working - it seems that i will also need to turn my array into a string - with JSON.stringify

Comment: Aha - yes i did need stringify on the way in and parse on the way out, my final, working code looks like:

Comment: function shuffleTavern() {
  var tavern = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('tavern'))
  tavern.sort(random);
  console.log(tavern);
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('tavern',JSON.stringify(tavern))