# Create a file with the same name as the folder where a file was uploaded

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have an HTML form within a Web App, created with GAS.

This HTML form was created from this file upload script here:

[drive-multi-upload](https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload)

This is the HTML form:

[image]

The point is that I needed the files to be uploaded in folders that follow the following pattern:
[image]

The first number refers to the **model selected** on the form, the second number refers to the **slot used**.

Therefore, it was necessary to create a function to identify the `input` chosen in the `Model` and, according to this `input`, check which is the first empty folder, then take the `ID` of that folder and pass it to the client side to upload the file inside it.

With the help of some members of the community, some adaptations were made and the final function was this:

```
    /** Modified version of script written by Tanaike */
    function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
      try {
        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId), folder;
        if (parentFolder) {
          var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
          if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
            var videoFolder = foldersIter.next();
            var nextFolderName = folderName + "-01";
            while (!folder) {
              video_folder = videoFolder.getFoldersByName(nextFolderName);
              if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
                folder = video_folder.next();
                var files = folder.getFiles();
                if (files.hasNext()) {
                  var [a, b] = nextFolderName.split("-");
                  nextFolderName = `${a}-${String(Number(b) + 1).padStart(2, "0")}`;
                  folder = null;
                }
              } else {
                folder = videoFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
              }
            }
          } else {
            folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
            folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
        }
        return folder.getId();
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    }
```

It works perfectly, the point is that this form also has a function that generates a .csv file when the form is submitted, the function is this one:

`.gs` file:

```
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile("Sample.csv", data);
```

`HTML` file:

```
var name = $('#name01').val();
      var description = $('#description').val();
      var model = $('#Model').val();
      upload_folder = model;
      var color = $('#Color').val();
      var form_values = [name, description, model, color];
      var data = form_values.join(",");

google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
```

My goal is to make the .csv file be generated with the same name as the folder where the file was uploaded, that is, if the file is uploaded in folder `01-01`, the file name has to be `01-01.csv`, if the file is uploaded in the `02-02` folder, the file name has to be `02-02.csv`, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

The complete script code can be viewed here:

`.gs` file:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('forms0101.html').evaluate();
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}


function getParent(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var id = ss.getId();
  var parent = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents().next().getId();
  return parent
}

function getLimitFolder(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pastapai = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getId();
  return limitfolder;
}

function getFilesLimit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pastapai = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  var files = [];
  Logger.log(pastapai);
  //var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getId();
  var limitfolder = pastapai.next().getFoldersByName("_").next().getFiles();
  while(limitfolder.hasNext()){
    var file = limitfolder.next();
    files.push([file.getId()]);
  }
  console.log(files.length);
  return files.length;
}

//function testenumeroarquivos(){
//console.log(checkForFiles()); // When you use this line, you can see the filename of the files.
//}

/**
* creates a folder under a parent folder, and returns it's id. If the folder already exists
* then it is not created and it simply returns the id of the existing one
*/

function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId), folder;
    if (parentFolder) {
      var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
      if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
        var videoFolder = foldersIter.next();
        var nextFolderName = folderName + "-01";
        while (!folder) {
          video_folder = videoFolder.getFoldersByName(nextFolderName);
          if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
            folder = video_folder.next();
            var files = folder.getFiles();
            if (files.hasNext()) {
              var [a, b] = nextFolderName.split("-");
              nextFolderName = `${a}-${String(Number(b) + 1).padStart(2, "0")}`;
              folder = null;
            }
          } else {
            folder = videoFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
          }
        }
      } else {
        folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
        folder = folder.createFolder(folderName);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }
    console.log("Test" + nextFolderName)
    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}


const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  folder.createFile(`${nextFolderName.getName()}.csv`, data);
}
const increaseRequest = (data, folderId) => DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile("IncreaseRequest.csv", data);


// NOTE: always make sure we use DriveApp, even if it's in a comment, for google to import those
// libraries and allow the rest of the app to work. see https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
```

`HTML` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drive Multi Large File Upload</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
     
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
      
      .disclaimer{
        width: 480px; 
        color: #646464;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding:0 16px;
        text-align:center;
        font:400 12px Rubik,sans-serif;
        }

      h5.center-align.teal-text {
        font:700 26px Rubik,sans-serif;
        color: #00F498!important;
      }

      .row {
        font:600 14px Rubik,sans-serif;
      }

      .btn {
        background-color: black;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        background-color: #00F498;
      }

      body {
        margin-top: -40px;
      }

      #progress {
        color: #00000;
      }
      
      .disclaimer a{
        color: #00BCAA;
        }

      #credit{
        display:none
        }

        .btnOpenModal {
  font-size: x-large;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

hr {
  border: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.active {
  display: flex;
}

.active .modal {
  animation: modal .4s;
}

@keyframes modal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.btns button {
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnOK {
 background-color: blue!important;
}

.btnClose {
  background-color: brown!important;
 }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
 <div id="forminner">


  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <hr />
      <span>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
         ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of 
         type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
      </span>
      <hr />
      <div class="btns">
        <button class="btnOK" onclick="increaseRequest(); closeModal();">OK</button>
        <button class="btnClose" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">YOUR NAME</h5>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="name01" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      <h5 class="center-align teal-text" style="margin-bottom: -10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Rubik; ">SOME DESCRIPTION</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="description" type="text" name="Description" class="validate" required="required" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name">Description</label>
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <h6>Model</h6>       
        <select class="custom-select" id="Model">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
        </select> 
          &nbsp;

        <h6>Color</h6>        
        <select class="custom-select" id="Color">
          <option selected="">Choose...</option>
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Green">Green</option>
        </select>   
      </div>
  </div>

    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Upload the Video File</h5>
           
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
            <div id="input-btn" class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input id="files" type="file" single="">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Select the file">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <button id="submit-btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 hide" id="update">
            <hr>
            <p>
              Por favor, aguarde enquanto seu arquivo está sendo carregado.<br><span style="color: #00000;"><b>Não feche ou atualize a janela durante o upload.</b></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id="progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Tudo certo!</h5>
        <p>Se você já preencheu todos os campos é só fechar essa janela e clicar em enviar!</p>
        <button id="fechar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" style ="transform: translateX(160%);" type="button" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Fechar</button>
      </div>

    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

    <script>
      var upload_folder = "01";
      const chunkSize = 5242880;
      const uploadParentFolderId = <?=getParent()?>; // creates a folder inside of this folder
      const limitfolder = <?=getLimitFolder()?>;
      const fileslimit = <?=getFilesLimit()?>;
      const modal = document.querySelector('.modal-container');

      var name = $('#name01').val();
      var description = $('#description').val();
      var model = $('#Model').val();
      upload_folder = model;
      var color = $('#Color').val();
      var form_values = [name, description, model, color];
      form_values = form_values.map(r => r.replaceAll(",", "#")); // Essa linha substitui todas as "," por "#" antes de gerar o .csv
      var data = form_values.join(",");


      function submitForm() {

      var name = $('#name01').val();
      var description = $('#description').val();
      var model = $('#Model').val();
      upload_folder = model;
      var color = $('#Color').val();
      var form_values = [name, description, model, color];
      form_values = form_values.map(r => r.replaceAll(",", "#")); // Essa linha substitui todas as "," por "#" antes de gerar o .csv
      var data = form_values.join(",");

        // Added the below script.
        if ($('#submit-btn.disabled')[0]) return; // short circuit

        var name = upload_folder
        var files = [...$('#files')[0].files]; // convert from FileList to array

        
        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Por favor, selecione um arquivo");
          return;
        }

        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
        google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, limitfolder);

        disableForm(); // prevent re submission

        // the map and reduce are here to ensure that only one file is uploaded at a time. This allows
        // the promises to be run sequentially
        files.map(file => uploadFilePromiseFactory(file))
            .reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
              return promiseChain.then(currentTask);
            }, Promise.resolve([])).then( () => {
              console.log("Completed all files upload");
              showSuccess();
            });
      }

      function checkforfiles() {
        
        if (fileslimit <= 2) {
        submitForm();
      }
        if (fileslimit == 3) {
        openModal();
      } 
        if (fileslimit >= 4) {
        showError("erro");
        return;
      }
        
      }
      
      function openModal() {
      modal.classList.add('active');
       }

      function closeModal() {
      modal.classList.remove('active');
      }
      
      function increaseRequest() {
      google.script.run.increaseRequest(data, limitfolder);
      }


      function disableForm() {
        $('#submit-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#input-btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#update').removeClass('hide');
         $('#update').removeClass('hide');
      }

       function closer(){
        google.script.host.close();
      }

      function uploadFilePromiseFactory(file) {
        return () => {
          console.log("Processing: ", file.name);
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            showProgressMessage("Seu arquivo está sendo carregado");

            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.fileName = file.name;
            fr.fileSize = file.size;
            fr.fileType = file.type;
            // not sure of a better way of passing the promise functions down
            fr.resolve = () => resolve();
            fr.reject = (error) => reject(error);
            fr.onload = onFileReaderLoad;
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          });
        };
      }
      
      /**
       * Gets called once the browser has loaded a file. The main logic that creates a folder
       * and initiates the file upload resides here
       */
      function onFileReaderLoad(onLoadEvent) {
        var fr = this;

        var newFolderName = upload_folder
        createOrGetFolder(newFolderName, uploadParentFolderId).then(newFolderId => {
          console.log("Found or created guest folder with id: ", newFolderId);
          uploadFileToDriveFolder.call(fr, newFolderId).then(() => {
              fr.resolve();
            }, (error) => {
              fr.reject(error);
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error) {
              showError(error.toString());
            }
            console.log("onFileReaderLoad Error2: ", error);
          });

      }

      /**
       * call to the DriveApp api. Wrapped in a promise in case I want to address timing issues between a
       * createFolder and findFolderById
       */
      function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(response => {
            console.log("createOrGetFolder response: ", response);
            if (response && response.length) {
              resolve(response);
            }
            reject(response);
          }).createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function uploadFileToDriveFolder(parentFolderId) {
        var fr = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var fileName = fr.fileName;
          var fileSize = fr.fileSize;
          var fileType = fr.fileType;
          console.log({fileName: fileName, fileSize: fileSize, fileType: fileType});
          var buf = fr.result;
          var chunkpot = getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize);
          var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
          var chunks = chunkpot.chunks.map(function(e) {
            return {
               data: uint8Array.slice(e.startByte, e.endByte + 1),
               length: e.numByte,
               range: "bytes " + e.startByte + "-" + e.endByte + "/" + chunkpot.total,
            };
          });
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(oAuthToken => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + oAuthToken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
              mimeType: fileType,
              name: fileName,
              parents: [parentFolderId]
            }));
            xhr.onload = () => {
              doUpload(fileName, {
                location: xhr.getResponseHeader("location"),
                chunks: chunks,
              }).then(success => {
                resolve(success);
                console.log("Successfully uploaded: ", fileName);
              },
              error => {
                reject(error);
              });
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log("ERROR: ", xhr.response);
              reject(xhr.response);
            };
          }).getOAuthToken();
        });
      }

      function showSuccess() {
        $('#forminner').hide();
        $('#success').show();
        $('#fechar').show();
      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#update').html(e);
      }

      function showProgressMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function doUpload(fileName, e) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" + "0%</span>");
          var chunks = e.chunks;
          var location = e.location;
          var cnt = 0;
          var end = chunks.length;
          var temp = function callback(cnt) {
            var e = chunks[cnt];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
            console.log("content range: ", e.range);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
            xhr.send(e.data);
            xhr.onloadend = function() {
                var status = xhr.status;
                cnt += 1;
                console.log("Uploading: " + status + " (" + cnt + " / " + end + ")");
                showProgressMessage("Carregando: <span style='color: #00F498 ;'>" 
                       + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>" );
                if (status == 308) {
                    callback(cnt);
                } else if (status == 200) {
                    $("#progress").text("Done.");
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    $("#progress").text("Error: " + xhr.response);
                    reject();
                }
            };
          }(cnt);
        });
      }

      /**
      * Helper functions modified from:
      * https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps
      */
      function getChunkpot(chunkSize, fileSize) {
        var chunkPot = {};
        chunkPot.total = fileSize;
        chunkPot.chunks = [];
        if (fileSize > chunkSize) {
            var numE = chunkSize;
            var endS = function(f, n) {
                var c = f % n;
                if (c == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }(fileSize, numE);
            var repeat = Math.floor(fileSize / numE);
            for (var i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
                var startAddress = i * numE;
                var c = {};
                c.startByte = startAddress;
                if (i < repeat) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + numE - 1;
                    c.numByte = numE;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                } else if (i == repeat && endS > 0) {
                    c.endByte = startAddress + endS - 1;
                    c.numByte = endS;
                    chunkPot.chunks.push(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var chunk = {
                startByte: 0,
                endByte: fileSize - 1,
                numByte: fileSize,
            };
            chunkPot.chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        return chunkPot;
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

It can also be viewed by accessing [this worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IjnDqQBYgq2D8qBALuI1VdBukNLe_Gycmk_JW1gv2JI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your whole script. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your whole script, I cannot still understand your expected result. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your expected result. When I could correctly understand your expected result, I would like to think of a solution. So, in the current stage, I have to delete my answer. Because I think that my answer is not useful for your actual expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: By the way, from my answer and your reply to my answer, I think that in your question, it is required to know your whole script. Because your showing script is a part of your whole script. So, even when your showing script is modified, as the result, your actual expected result cannot be obtained. I think that this leads to the difference in understanding your actual expected result. I'm worried about this.

Comment: And, unfortunately, when I tested your provided whole script, I cannot replicate your current situation from your provided whole script. I think that first, it is required to correctly replicate your situation before I modify your script. So, please confirm your whole script again.

Comment: Hi. I'm really please that @Tanaike has responded to your question. But you'll also understand that your question needs to stand on its own, and that it's not appropriate to expect volunteers/users to have to access a sheet to see the layout or full code. In fact, there is no guarantee that the link to your sheet will be valid for future users. So would you please edit your question to include the full script.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for your always support. I would like to wait for the OP to modify the question for helping to think of a solution because I would like to support it.

Comment: @Tedinoz Sorry about that, I was afraid to put all the code here and get too confused, it's quite long and I thought the spreadsheet would be better to visualize, but I understand the point of availability for future users. I will publish the whole code and also the spreadsheet link, is that ok? So I think it makes it easier to see.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks so much for all your help and support. I added a `console.log("Test" + nextFolderName)` line to the script and I was able to prove that what I really need is that the .csv file name is the same as nextFolderName, the issue is that I am not able to access it outside the function . How can I do this?

Comment: I tried this: `const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId) => {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  folder.createFile(`${nextFolderName.getName()}.csv`, data);
}` But it did not work...

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual expected result, I proposed a modified script. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that's exactly it!!
Thank you so much for your help and patience. I'm sorry for the confusion in trying to explain, I'm a beginner and I have a difficulty, but I'm trying hard to evolve. It made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual expected result, please test the following modification.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `saveDataAsCSV` of Google Apps Script as follows.

```js
const saveDataAsCSV = (data, folderId1, folderId2 = null) => {
  if (folderId2) {
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId1).createFile(`${DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId2).getName()}.csv`, data);
  } else {
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId1).createFile("sample.csv", data);
  }
}
```

#### Javascript side:

Please remove `google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);` in the function `submitForm`.

And, please modify `onFileReaderLoad` of Javascript as follows.

```js
function onFileReaderLoad(onLoadEvent) {
  var fr = this;
  var newFolderName = upload_folder
  createOrGetFolder(newFolderName, uploadParentFolderId).then(newFolderId => {
    google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId, newFolderId);
    console.log("Found or created guest folder with id: ", newFolderId);
    uploadFileToDriveFolder.call(fr, newFolderId).then(() => {
      fr.resolve();
    }, (error) => {
      fr.reject(error);
    });
  },
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        showError(error.toString());
      }
      console.log("onFileReaderLoad Error2: ", error);
    });
}
```

- By this modification, I think that a CSV file like `01-01.csv` is created to `uploadParentFolderId` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and attention.
That's almost it, this way the file was created with the name of the parent folder `Stack Thread - Demonstration`, I need it to be created with the name of the folder where the video file was uploaded.

I edited my question to show the result I got and explain more about my goal

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe what I need is for the file name to be the same as `nextFolderName`

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your script, I guessed that `uploadParentFolderId` of `google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);` is the folder you want to save. So, I proposed it. But from your reply and your updated question, it seems that my guess was not correct. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt In this case, in order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about the detail of your situation? Because I cannot know the relationship between `google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);` and your expected folder. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt And, can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between `uploadParentFolderId` of `google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);` and `createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId)`? I deeply apologize that I am trying to understand your question correctly.

Comment: I confess that I do not know how to explain this well, but I will try. The .csv file is generated with the form responses, you taught me how to do that in this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168406/19538465). The numbered upload folders are inside the `Video` folder, which is inside the parent folder. As I explained in the question, every time a file is uploaded, the folder changes according to the availability of slots, you taught me how to do that in this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190640/19538465)

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current whole script?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, when I refer to file upload, I am referring to the file that is uploaded in the form, not the generated .csv file. The .csv file is generated inside the parent folder and this is correct, what I need is for it to have the same name as the folder where the video file was uploaded.

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. Where can I see your whole script in your provided Spreadsheet?

Comment: Just a minute, I'll arrange

Comment: Sorry, someone had deleted all the script that was in this spreadsheet, but I have backups and you can see it in the GAS of [this spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IjnDqQBYgq2D8qBALuI1VdBukNLe_Gycmk_JW1gv2JI/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying and providing your whole script. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your whole script, I cannot still understand your expected result. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your expected result. When I could correctly understand your expected result, I would like to think of a solution. So, in the current stage, I have to delete my answer. Because I think that my answer is not useful for your actual expected result. I apologize for my poor English skill again.